# COALESCE doesnt work with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, coalesce

I tried so many times but not any efficent.

**My tried 3 queries:**

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(links.name, 'noname') as owner FROM links");

 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(links.name, users.username) as owner FROM links");

 $this->db->select("COALESCE(links.name, 'noname') as owner", false);
```

1. Users table joined
2. Tried without join
3. CodeIgniter version `2.1.4`
4. MySql version `5.5.24`

I just want show name which not `NULL`. If `links.name` is NULL, get `users.username`

But i couldnt figure out.

#### Result is always following

```
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'owner' => string 'John Doe' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'owner' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'owner' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(name, 'noname') as owner FROM links

Comment: @Mihai Tried before, not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting empty strings. That means the `links.name` field in the record isn't NULL, it's an empty string. coalesce() only triggers if you're actually using a full-blowin SQL `NULL` value. Empty strings aren't null, they're just strings that happen to be empty.

Probably this'd work

```
SELECT IF(links.name='', 'noname', links.name) AS owner
```

Comment: Great answer! Definitely it works. And thank you for explanation. I got it. So how can get empty columns as `NULL` default, is it possible?

Comment: depends on how you're inserting them and if the field's actually nullable.

Comment: Arrgh! I have not had it as `default value NULL`. So `COALESCE` works now ;)